# Oauth 2.0 Authentication Scheme apiary apiblueprint example needed

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary

I have a REST API which uses Azure Active Directory and OAuth 2.0 to authenticate. 
How can I set this up using api blueprint in apiary.

I can see it works for http://docs.powerbi.apiary.io/

Just cannot seem to find an example.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

actually APIBlueprint does not support any authentication scheme.

However, something is definitely moving in the right direction: you can notice it looking at [this pr](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/pull/201) and its [subsequent discussion](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint-rfcs/blob/master/draft/0002-authentication.md)

Actually Apiary has some sort of private-beta OAuth 2 support but it is enabled on request and it's definitely not a feature of APIBlueprint itself (yet).

I hope this clarifies the issue.